# Cannot find module after importing

Tags: python, jwt, conda, fastapi, passlib

I'm currently following this [tutorial](https://christophergs.com/tutorials/ultimate-fastapi-tutorial-pt-10-auth-jwt/), and I'm stuck on running the program. I have a conda environment set up, with all of the necessary packages downloaded, but when I run the program, I receive the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'passlib'
```

I've run `conda list | grep pass` and it shows that I do have passlib downloaded.

```
passlib                   1.7.4              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
```

I've tried uninstalling, reinstalling, running a new terminal, and nothing works. Any ideas on how to get the environment to recognize that `passlib` is installed?

NOTE: I'm using bash to run the .sh scripts and not poetry, since I've had some trouble with poetry.

Comment: So how are you running your program? Are you sure that it's using the same environment as given by `conda list`?

Comment: @MatsLindh I'm inside a conda env that I created, and then running `bash run.sh`, and the run.sh file is a run file which is under part 10 of this [link](https://github.com/ChristopherGS/ultimate-fastapi-tutorial/tree/main/part-01-hello-world). It runs the uvicorn instance, but then errors out on passlib.